# Spring boot - connect hibernate with one oracle huge table

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, groovy

I am creating a spring boot application and I only have one table in my oracle database (one table with more than 80 fields...), so, what is the best way to implement this in my spring boot-groovy app?
Do I need to have one entity with 80 attributes?? 
Can I have a hibernate entity model different from the awful oracle model? (having more than one entity in my app but connected with the same huge table).

Any ideas or tools are more than welcome.

Comment: Is having a properly designed Oracle schema out of the question?

Comment: no, the database is just... awful, but I cannot touch oracle